# Apply random_shear augment to image tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to apply `random_shear` image augmentation from Keras but the images are completely distorted after this.

```
shape = inputs.shape #(32,512,512,3)

temp = np.empty(shape=(shape[0], shape[1],shape[2], shape[3]))

for i in range(shape[0]):
    array_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(inputs[i])
    sheared = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(array_inputs, .2,
                                            row_axis=0, col_axis=1,
                                            channel_axis=2)
    temp[i]= sheared
return tf.convert_to_tensor(temp)
```

I am not sure what is wrong here.
Can anybody help me here?

Comment: I run your code with `inputs` as list of PIL Image instance and every thing is working fine, can you show more info about you `inputs`, and how images are distorted? did you using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img` after `random_shear` and before show the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what is worth, here is the code I tested:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

inputs = [Image.open('./homersimpson.0.0.jpg')]
shape = (1,1400,1400,3)

temp = np.empty(shape=(shape[0], shape[1],shape[2], shape[3]))

for i in range(shape[0]):
    array_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(inputs[i])
    sheared = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(array_inputs, 50,
                                            row_axis=0, col_axis=1,
                                            channel_axis=2)
    temp[i]= sheared

for i in range(shape[0]):
    tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(temp[i]).show()
```

Turning this image:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: Yea, the code works, I had an issue in the code just before this piece of code. Thanks

Comment: Hi, how will the code change if the dimension is (None, 32, 32, 3). Basically, if the first dimension is unknown.

Comment: @AshwaniK then the code will not work, you should know how many images you have before process the images, you could however, make this process as the function with number of images as parameter, and call it whenever you load the images

Comment: @AshwaniK And you could also using the [preprocessing_layers in keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#image_data_augmentation_on-device), but this is not recommend because it will call on every inputs to the model thus slow down the training

Comment: Actually, I am implementing a custom preprocessing layer for RandomShear and the current code does not work and the dimension is (None, 32, 32,3) thus not working.